# C++: Trying to understand constexpr through combinations and Pascal's Triangle

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, combinations, constexpr

I know that `constexpr` is supposed to allow the elimination / simplification of many template programming tricks used in the past, but I'm still fairly new to C++11 on and I am having trouble understanding why, in calculating the combination function:

`C(n,r) = n!/(r!(n-r)!) = C(n-1,r-1) + C(n-1,r)`

The recursive approach, which is ridiculously slow when executed at runtime as would be expected, but allows calculations of `C(n,r)` for much larger values, works just fine with templates, but I cannot get it to work with `constexpr`. Here is the template code I'm using:

```
using factorial_t = unsigned long long;

template<size_t N, size_t R>
struct recursive_combinations {
    enum: factorial_t { value = recursive_combinations<N-1, R>::value +
                                recursive_combinations<N-1, R-1>::value};
};

template<size_t N>
struct recursive_combinations<N,0> {
    enum: factorial_t { value = 1 };
};

template<size_t N>
struct recursive_combinations<N,N> {
    enum: factorial_t { value = 1 };
};
```

and here is the `constexpr` version (maybe I am doing something wrong here):

```
constexpr const factorial_t recursiveCombinations(const size_t N, const size_t R) {
    if (R == N || R == 0) return 1;
    return recursiveCombinations(N-1, R) + recursiveCombinations(N-1, R-1);
}
```

When I try this:

```
constexpr auto comb1_50_30 = recursive_combinations<50,30>::value;
```

everything is just fine, and I get the expected result of 47,129,212,243,960, which is unobtainable from calculating the factorials.

However, when I try this:

```
constexpr auto comb2_50_30 = recursiveCombinations(50, 30);
```

the compiler (clang v5.0.1, set to C++17 mode) complains that `comb2_50_30` must be initialized by a constant expression.

Can somebody help me figure out what I'm doing wrong or if there is a way to get this to work with `constexpr` (and if not, why not)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the cost of reducing the limit of the result by one factor of `min(r, n-r)`, you can use the following far more efficient implementation:

```
constexpr uint64_t efficientCombinations(uint64_t n, uint64_t r)
{
    uint64_t accum = 1U;
    if (n - r > r) r = n - r;
    for( uint64_t x = 1; x <= n - r; ++x )
    {
        accum *= (r + x);
        accum /= x;
    }
    return accum;
}
```

For compatibility with C++11, transforming this iteration to recursion is straightforward if a bit messy.

(Note: depending on what the question meant by "get *this* to work", changing the algorithm like this might not be the desired approach... but it's too big for a comment)

Comment: Nice! I was just playing around, as I'm trying to get up to speed with modern C++ since I've been long stuck in C++98. This is a great solution that compiles fine under both compilers and works. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 3):

> complains that comb2_50_30 must be initialized by a constant expression.

The next line of the error tells you why:

```
note: constexpr evaluation hit maximum step limit; possible infinite loop?
```

Your expansion is simply too computationally expensive for `constexpr` evaluation. You can use `-fconstexpr-steps=X` and `-fconstexpr-depth=X` to increase the amount of effort the compiler is allowed to compute a `constexpr` function, but I didn't manage to find values that allowed your `recursiveCombinations(50, 30)` to compile on clang.

g++ compiles the `constexpr` version just fine.

Comment: Ahhh... yes, you're right! It seems to work fine with GCC7.

Comment: In addition, template has memoization guaranteed (each instance is instantiated once) whereas for `constexpr`, it is not the case (How many times `recursiveCombinations(48, 29)` is computed ?)